# Php(sessions)...how to put textbox value in session and pass it to another page?i m getting error

Tags: php

```
<?php
session_start();
 ?>
 <form action="HardDisk.php" method="post">//form
 <input type="text" name="user" />
 <?php
if(isset($_POST['user']))
 {
 $_SESSION['userGet']=$_POST['user'];
 }
 ?>
 <input type="submit" value="submit" />
 </form>

  2nd page
 <?php
 session_start();
 ?>
 <?php
 if (isset($_SESSION['userGet'])) {
$form_value = $_SESSION['userGet'];
}
echo $form_value ;
?>
```

..........................................................................................................

Comment: pls describe your problem? What do you want to happen and what happens?

Comment: i want to move the textbox data to another page by session

Comment: Do you have `session_start()` at the top of each page?

Comment: yes ...forget to mention here

Comment: Syntax issue `$_SESSION[userGet']` in the second page.

Comment: it is not syntax as i manually type  code here that why.i  having  this error Undefined variable: form_value in C:\xampp\htdocs\myPages\HardDisk.php on line 17

Comment: Well that is easy to fix: `if (isset($_SESSION['userGet'])) { $form_value = $_SESSION['userGet']; echo $form_value ; }`

Comment: why not more easy fix `if (!empty($_SESSION['userGet'])) { $form_value = $_SESSION['userGet']; echo $form_value ; } else { //set your error here }`

Answer (score 1):

You have used the text box name with that check the submit button name too.

```
 <form action="HardDisk.php" method="post">//form
 <input type="text" name="user" />
 <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
 </form>
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])&&isset($_POST['user'])) {
    $_SESSION['userGet']=$_POST['user'];
}
?>
```

And in your second page

```
<?php
session_start(); 
if (isset($_SESSION['userGet'])) {
    echo $form_value = $_SESSION['userGet'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the submit button a name of submit then use the following PHP code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(isset($_POST['user']))
    {
        $_SESSION['userGet']=$_POST['user'];
    }
}
```